# How to delete archive log on just one dest?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I have two archive_log_dest, I need to delete archivelog on dest1 until today. I need to keep on archive_log_dest2 all archive. How can I do that with rman?

Answer (score 2):

```
rman target /
RMAN> delete archivelog like '/path/to/logs/%';
```

[archivelogRecordSpecifier](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10643/rcmsubcl002.htm#BGBGGEHD)

[image]